# いいちんぽみ〜っけ！ What does that mean?

Tags: grammar

(ii chinpomi~kke!) I know what the censored word is, but what does all the sentence mean? It can be divided? I think that いい and ちんぽ can, but it's "み" connected to ちんぽ, and/or is っけ connected to み?

Comment: You wrote "the censored word", but you don't appear to have censored anything.  You could probably ask this question without using that word specifically, though, and just focus on み～っけ.

Answer (score 4):

「み〜っけ」appears to be just a colloquial form for "見つけた". So this means "I've found a great (your censored word)".

Comment: To add some more info, 「みっけ」 is what kids say upon finding someone in hide-and-seek.  They sort of continue saying it into adulthood to say "Found st/so!" in a COMMICAL way just like a child.  Thus it is not  a simple  "colloquial" form.